# Alter column length doesn't update syscolumns length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an existing table with an NVARCHAR(8000) field.  I also have a procedure that builds an audit table by examining `syscolumns` (among others) to replicate source table schema.

If I run the following statement against the existing source table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn NVARCHAR(4000);
```

and then run a query against syscolumns:

```
SELECT b.name, c.name as TypeName, b.length, b.isnullable, b.collation, b.xprec, b.xscale
FROM sysobjects a 
INNER JOIN syscolumns b on a.id = b.id 
INNER JOIN systypes c on b.xtype = c.xtype and c.name <> 'sysname' 
WHERE a.id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CalendarEvents]') 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(a.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1 
ORDER BY b.colId
```

... the syscolumn length still reports 8000 instead of the new 4000.

Is there a way I can force-refresh this?  Presumably there's some internal maintenance that updates these periodically, but I'm not sure what the rules are and it's interfering with my ability to build the audit objects directly after altering the column length in the source table.

Comment: Possible cause: NVARCHAR stores 2 bytes per char, and 2 * 4000 = 8000. And NVARCHAR(8000) isn't even possible, it is either a value upto 4000, or MAX.

Comment: @PeterB - you're correct: just checked on a separate 255 field that's reporting 510 in syscolumns.  I'll update my audit creation sproc to cut that number in half if NVARCHAR.  Toss it in an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Comment: Surprised you can declare an `nvarchar(8000)`.Maximum size of an `nvarchar` is 4000. if you need more characters than that, you have to use `nvarchar(MAX)`. Running the query `DECLARE @n nvarchar(8000);` would return the error `The size (8000) given to the parameter '@n' exceeds the maximum allowed (4000).`

Comment: @Larnu - can't do it actually - I got mixed up somehow, somewhere, but I just verified that you can't create an nvarchar(8000).

Comment: I don't think is really a question anymore. The OP misunderstood the data being returned. It is 100% accurate that an nvarchar(4000) reports 8,000 as the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is that `NVARCHAR` stores 2 bytes per char, and 2 * 4000 = 8000.

Also `NVARCHAR(8000)` isn't even possible, you can use either a length value upto 4000, or the special keyword `MAX` which makes it limited to 2GB but with values stored separately from the table if needed.

Answer (score 1):

> **max_length**    smallint    Maximum length (**in bytes**) of the column.
>
> -1 = Column data type is varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), or xml.
>
> For text columns, the max_length value will be 16 or the value set by
>   sp_tableoption 'text in row'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql

And for NVARCHAR:

> The actual storage size, in bytes, is **two times the number of characters** ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql

This means, that the reported max_lenght for any NVARCHAR and NCHAR columns will be 2 times the allowed lenght (except for NVARCHAR(MAX) and CHAR(MAX) in which case, you'll see -1).

BTW, `syscolumns` is deprecated, use `sys.columns` instead.